# Could Extra-Galactic invasion have been averted with the Empire in control?

Tags: star-wars, aliens, yuuzhan-vong

As I understand the Rebellion was formed to overthrow the Empire and replace it with a Democratic government. According to http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong the Emperor was aware of the presence of a massive invasion force of 
extra-galactic Yuuzhan Vong after a scouting mission was intercepted by the Aliens.

That was supposedly his real justification for opening hundreds of cloning facilities and recruitment facilities as well as further industrializing the Empire. After the Rebellion overthrew the Empire the Galaxy was sent into an economic depression and was plagued by war. This made it relatively easy for the Yuuzhan Vong to conquer most of the Galaxy for a time.

My question is: Would the Empire have been able to stop or at least hold at bay the Vong long enough to work out a treaty? If this was to occur, how could it have affected the galaxy for the better or worse?

Comment: According to the Star Wars Wiki, the Vong killed 365 trillion sentients during their invasion. My guess is that ***anything*** would have been better.

Comment: Two intact Death Stars and an Imperial military that hadn't been depleted by rebellion certainly would have had an easier time repelling the Yuuzhan Vong.

Comment: In the long run, however, the galaxy ended up living in freedom with no Empire *and* no Yuuzhan Vong.

Comment: Having completed an answer, I've come to the conclusion that this is very speculative. There's certainly no decent "Legends" canon answer that I'm aware of.

Comment: Really. You upvote my question then put it on hold?

Comment: @DustinJackson - I didn't upvote it, nor did I downvote it. As it stands, it's very opinion-based. My opinion is yes, but I've no objective basis for thinking so. Maybe it would have been worse with the Empire still in charge. Using the Death Star could have made the Vong really angry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with all post-war analysis (AKA armchair quarterbacking) the question is how far into the future you want to look. Yes, in the very short term the death of the Emperor and the rise of the rebellion threw the Empire into turmoil and made it easier for the Yuuzhan Vong to invade. With the Imperial fleet in disarray, both Death Stars destroyed and many petty warlords fighting among themselves for control, the Vong certainly enjoyed vastly more success than they would have had had they faced a coordinated Empire at the height of its power.

Some 365 trillion sentients died during their aborted invasion. Would as many have died with the Empire still in control? Probably not.

Would the Vong have attempted the invasion anyway? Probably yes given the vast distances they'd already covered in order to reach the Galaxy.

The Empire was oppressive and unpleasant (boo!) whereas the New Republic were warm and fluffy (yay!). Would the peoples of the Galaxy have chosen to leave the Emperor in charge in order to avoid trillions of deaths? **Almost certainly yes**. For the majority of people living on planets inside and outside the Empire, a change of regime probably meant almost nothing to them and wasn't worth dying for.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that the Vong hated non-organic technology and would probably have attacked the Empire for that reason (for example, the Death Star was a "technological terror").

Comment: @Null - As I said, they'd come a long way and didn't plan to live under the Empire (or anyone else's) control. Invasion was inevitable.

Comment: although the Republic was just as corrupt in many areas, if not more so than the Empire(lol warm and fluffy) I tend to agree that it would have been better for the Galaxy had the Empire remained in power for at least as long as it took to repel the Yuuzhan Vong. I guess this is more of a matter of opinion though, but it is fun to debate:)

Comment: @Richard The wiki page actually mentions that there were still swathes of unexplored space. The Vong could have attempted to settle that space since they had strong terraforming.....plant tech?

Comment: @DustinJackson - Unfortunately, this site isn't configured for debate, it's about getting definitive answers.

Comment: @Richard I was just stating that it is fun to debate....my whole family is Star Wars freaks and I was curious as to what would have been better for the galaxy. I was thinking aloud in my earlier comment.